# Wordpress: How to make unique field with ACF and custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, unique, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

So I'm working on a custom post type to work together with Advanced custom fields. And I have this little script that is supposed to block duplicate emails from being entered. But the script does not work as I want it to.

The code that u see below is for the custom post type page that I've linked to ACF.

```
function init_members() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Members',
        'singular_name'      => 'Member',
        'menu_name'          => 'Members',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Member',
        'add_new'            => 'New member',
        'add_new_item'       => 'New member',
        'new_item'           => 'New member',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit member',
        'all_items'          => 'All members',
        'search_items'       => 'Search member',
        'not_found'          => 'No members found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No members found in trash'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member'),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array('title'),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups'

    );
    register_post_type('members', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'init_members');
```

---

```
function add_member_columns ( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['date']);
    return array_merge ( $columns, array (
        'contactperson'   => __ ( 'Contactperson' ),
        'phone_number'   => __ ( 'Phonenumber' ),
        'email'   => __ ( 'Email' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter ('manage_members_posts_columns', 'add_member_columns' );

function fill_member_columns ( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'contactperson':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'contactperson', true );
            break;
        case 'phone_number':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'phone_number', true );
            break;
        case 'email':
            echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'email', true );
            break;
    }
}
add_action ('manage_members_posts_custom_column', 'fill_member_columns', 10, 2 );
```

---

So the script I have for trying to filter the use of duplicate emails is as follows.
the source where I got it from is [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/accept-only-unique-values/)

```
add_filter('acf/validate_value/name='.'email', 'acf_unique_value_field', 10, 4);

function acf_unique_value_field($valid, $value, $field, $input) {
    if (!$valid || (!isset($_POST['post_ID']) && !isset($_POST['post_id']))) {
        return $valid;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['post_ID'])) {
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_ID']);
    } else {
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    }
    if (!$post_id) {
        return $valid;
    }
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $field_name = $field['name'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish, draft, trash',
        'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'email',
                'value' => $value
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if (count($query->posts)){
        return 'This Value is not Unique. Please enter a unique '.$field['label'];
    }
    return true;
}
```

I probably oversee something pretty obvious. But I'm not able to find what I'm overseeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you aren't querying **all** existing posts.  If your posts per page default is configured to 5, and the 6th post turns out to have the same mail address as the updated one, your check will not find any matching posts.

Try the following: in `acf_unique_value_field()`, fix your query like so:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish, draft, trash',
        'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'email',
                'value' => $value
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

`'posts_per_page' => -1,` will query an unlimited number of posts.

Also, I've seen you're using `get_post_meta` to retrieve ACF field values. I advise against doing so. Use ACF's `get_field` instead (and `update_field` for updating if necessary).

Comment: Thank u so much this fixed it completely.
the 'posts_per_page' => -1,